# position element on another with jQuery UI position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

Heyho again,
I have two elements and want to position one of it relative to the second one :-)
I found and would like to use "jquery ui .position()" for that. Here is what I got:

```
<div id="testparent">Parent</div>
<div id="testchild">Child</div>
#testparent{
    position: absolute;
   margin:100px auto auto auto;
   width:300px;
   height:120px;
   background:lime; 
}
#testchild{
    margin:auto;
    width:60px;
    height:90px;
    background:yellow;
}
$('#testchild').position({
    of: $('#testparent'),
    my: "left top",
    at: "left bottom",
    offset: "0 3"
});
```

I want the testchild to be positioned above/under the testparent. The problem is, that I do NOT want to position it horizontally relative to the parent but just vertically!!
Is that possible :-)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with only the `my` and `at` options, because specifying a single value will apply to both `left` and `top`.

You can, however, specify a function in the [using](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/#option-using) option, and that function will be called to perform positioning. If you ignore the `left` property and only update `top`, you can achieve what you want:

```
$("#testchild").position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left bottom",
    of: "#testparent",
    offset: "0 3",
    using: function(props) {
        $(this).css("top", props.top);
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah that solved my problem! only change I had to do: props is not defined. so the "element" param is enough and it has to be `$('#testchild').css("top", element.top);` Thank you!

Comment: You're right, the function only takes a single argument, and `this` is bound to the element. I updated my answer accordingly.